# split variable into multiple variables in loop

Tags: bash, variable

i am searching on these forums and trying different codes, but i cant seem to get it working:

i have a variable

```
ip="192.168.1.227 192.168.1.205 192.168.1.217"
```

no i want to split every ip address up in to different variables

```
ip1=192.168.1.227
ip2=192.168.1.205
ip3=192.168.1.217
```

i was trying to do something with word

```
for ((word in $vds; i=0; i++));
do
echo $word
"ip$i"=$word
done
```

but i cant get it working.

Comment: I added the "bash" tag as your code uses bash `for` loop syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the array clearly is the approach of choice, if you really really need the individual `ip$number` version, try

- `eval` your `ip$i=$word` assignment carefully looking at the quoting (with the  precautions reg. the deprecated `eval` in mind)
- a small loop like `for word in $ip; do read ip$((++CNT)) <<< $word; done`

Comment: **eval is evil**. An eval is more often than not an opportunity for code injection. The value of `$i` (or `$CNT`) should be sanitized with great care. It should never contain values from an external user.

Comment: ... and it's only deprecated in the sense that its use is not generally encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unlikely that you *actually* want separate variables for each individual IP number.  It would be more manageable to store the IP numbers in an array.

```
ipnumbers=( $ip )
```

This unquoted use of `$ip` would (assuming the default value of the `IFS` variable) split its value on whitespaces (and invoke filename globbing on the resulting words, but that should not be an issue since there is no filename globbing patterns in the data).  It would then assign the split up words as separate elements in the array `ipnumbers`.

You may then access the individual elements using e.g. `"${ipnumbers[1]}"` (for the second element), or loop over them with

```
for ipnum in "${ipnumbers[@]}"; do ...; done
```

Comment: Shouldn't the FIRST element be referenced by `"${ipnumbers[0]}"`?

Comment: @RudiC So it is! Thanks. I've been doing too much `awk` programming lately...

Comment: Shouldn't you ensure that IFS is correct to make this method robust?

Comment: @Isaac I added a note about this. AFAIK, `bash` resets `IFS` when a shell starts, so if it's left unchanged it will work.

Comment: Yes, sure, but you are providing an snippet (a one line part) that could be incorporated into any bigger/longer script. The note about the value of IFS is relevant and important in the this case.

Answer (score 1):

You will be better off by using an array variable.

```
 readarray -t -d ' ' ips <<<"$ip"
```

This doesn't use the "unquoted" shell splitting that is usually problematic with newlines, glob characters (`*`, `?`, `[]`) and what not. Then just print the array:

```
 printf '%s\n'  "${ips[@]}"
```

Or use it in a loop:

```
for i in "${ips[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```