# create menu with x items depending on variable

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to get a menu with x lines depending on a variable.

setup:

i have a network with x ip addresses

i want a user to get a menu where he can simply choose an ip address by entering a number:

for instance:

i have 4 ip adresses

```
ip1=192.168.1.1
ip2=192.168.1.2
ip3=192.168.1.3
ip4=192.168.1.4
```

i want the user to get a menu like

```
1. 192.168.1.1
2. 192.168.1.2
3. 192.168.1.3
4. 192.168.1.4
Please enter your choice:
```

however, the number of ip addresses can variate.

I am trying to do this in a case:

```
echo -n "Please enter your choice: "
read opt
case $opt in
    ipnum=ip$opt

    1)  echo ${!ipnum}
esac
```

but i cant get it into a loop

Comment: Any specific reason for using the `case` compound command? Wouldn't putting the IPs in an array and loop over it to print a menu be enough? E.g. `for i in "${!ips[@]}"; do  ... print menu item ... ; done; ... prompt ... ; read answer... ; ... use user's choice ...`

Comment: I am fairly new to this, so i am still trying to understand all the functions and what to use when.

I use case because i got an other menu working with it

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using `bash` (or a similar shell):

```
ipnums=( 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4 )

select ip in "${ipnums[@]}"; do
    case $ip in
        "") echo 'Invalid choice' >&2 ;;
        *)  break
    esac
done

printf 'You picked IP %s\n' "$ip"
```

This would display a menu and a prompt like this:

```
1) 192.168.1.1
2) 192.168.1.2
3) 192.168.1.3
4) 192.168.1.4
#?
```

The prompt may be changed by setting `PS3` to the prompt string to use.

The `select` loop verifies the input and loops until a valid input is had from the user.

After the loop, the IP address that was chosen is available in `$ip`.

If you don't want to store your addresses in an array, you would have to list the relevant variables instead (this would not easily be generalised to N variables, which is why I suggested using an array in my answer to [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487286)):

```
select ip in "$ip1" "$ip2" "$ip3" "$ip4"; do ...; done
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i figured it out.

like @fra-san said why use case and not just print it and ask for the users choice.

i just used an array to echo all ip addressing with an extra number in front, and when they enter the number it correspondences with the number in the variable, so i have my answer .